# My VS Code doesn't auto update changes in source control

Tags: visual-studio-code

After changing settings in the editor, the changes in the source control tab stopped updating automatically. I forgot which setting I had changed. Can you help me fix it?

Comment: there are a finite number of settings concerning SCM changed in your `settings.json` file, comment them one by one to find the culprit

Comment: git.autorefresh it's prop that we need